# React native app crashes when destroying the app, only on Android

Tags: android, react-native

When destroying the app, the app crashes with a com.facebook.react.bridge.NoSuchKeyException. This is exclusive to Android. The crash happens with both debug and release builds.

I have tried updating all of my packages, which did not fix the issue. I believe this is likely caused by a third party library, but I'm not sure how to track it down with the information I have.

Stack trace:

```
com.facebook.react.bridge.NoSuchKeyException lineNumber 
    ReadableNativeMap.java:124 com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap.getValue
    ReadableNativeMap.java:128 com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap.getValue
    ReadableNativeMap.java:182 com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap.getInt
    JSStackTrace.java:28 com.facebook.react.util.JSStackTrace.format
    ExceptionsManagerModule.java:46 com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportSoftException
    Method.java:-2 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
    JavaMethodWrapper.java:372 com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke
    JavaModuleWrapper.java:158 com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke
    NativeRunnable.java:-2 com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run
    Handler.java:873 android.os.Handler.handleCallback
    Handler.java:99 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage
    MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29 com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage
    Looper.java:193 android.os.Looper.loop
    MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:232 com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run
    Thread.java:764 java.lang.Thread.run
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "rnkirsofficer",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "version": "react-native-version"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mapbox/polyline": "^1.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.3.3",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^2.0.4",
    "aws-amplify": "^1.1.26",
    "aws-amplify-react-native": "^2.1.10",
    "bugsnag-react-native": "^2.16.0",
    "fuse.js": "^3.4.4",
    "haversine": "^1.1.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "native-base": "^2.12.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.4",
    "react-native-background-geolocation": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.32.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.7.2",
    "react-native-google-maps-directions": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.24.2",
    "react-native-maps-super-cluster": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-popup-menu": "^0.15.5",
    "react-native-svg": "^9.4.0",
    "react-native-svg-charts": "^5.2.0",
    "react-native-text-ticker": "^0.14.0",
    "react-native-version-number": "^0.3.5",
    "react-navigation": "^3.8.1",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "react-timeout": "^1.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.3.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.3.4",
    "babel-jest": "24.5.0",
    "husky": "^1.3.1",
    "jest": "24.5.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.53.1",
    "react-native-version": "^3.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

I expect the app to be able to be destroyed without crashing, but currently it crashes with a NoSuchKeyException.

Comment: `adb logcat` or if your os is osx, you can use flipper app for track app log.
https://fbflipper.com/
can you write app log on the terminal, when app crashed?

Comment: You probably added libraries not in a single batch, correct? Or it has happened from the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

Well,

Check if you have use Console.err() somewhere in your project.
If so remove those Console.err().